# How to limit the length of the title to 20 characters?

Tags: php, rss, title

How to limit the length of the title to 20 characters?

I am a newbie, Thanks =)

```
    <?php
    include("topic.php");
    $RSS = new topic("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml");
    for( $i = 0; $i < 11; $i++ )
    {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$RSS->link[$i].'" target="_blank">'.$RSS->title[$i].'</a></li>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function:

```
echo '<li><a href="'.$RSS->link[$i].'" target="_blank">'. substr($RSS->title[$i], 0, 20) .'</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Is The Modified Code

```
<?php
include("topic.php");
$RSS = new topic("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml");
for( $i = 0; $i < 11; $i++ )
{
  $sub_title = (strlen($RSS->title[$i]) > 20) ? substr($RSS->title[$i],0,20).'...' : $RSS->title[$i];
echo '<li><a href="'.$RSS->link[$i].'" target="_blank">'.$sub_title.'</a></li>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi =)
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$RSS' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/fortune/public_html/888.php on line 6

Answer (score 0):

Since you call yourself a newbie, I guess you'd appreciate some tips:

- Escape the strings using `htmlspecialchars` function to
  avoid security issues (eg: XSS attacks).
- Use the `mb_*` functions to avoid encoding problems.
- If you'd like to handle any items numbers, do not use hard coded
  numbers - use, for instance, a `foreach`.

If you'd like all these issues fixed and add ellipse titles larger than 20 characters, try this:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

include("topic.php");

$RSS = new topic("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml");
$titleMaxCharacters = 20;
foreach($RSS->link as $i => $link)
{
    $titleHtml = '';
    if( isset($RSS->title[$i]) ) {
        $title = $RSS->title[$i];
        $handledTitle = mb_strlen($title) > $titleMaxCharacters
                          ? mb_substr($title, 0, $titleMaxCharacters) . '...'
                          : $title;
        $titleHtml = htmlspecialchars($handledTitle, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }

    $linkHtml = htmlspecialchars($link, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');

    echo '<li><a href="'.$linkHtml.'" target="_blank">'.$titleHtml.'</a></li>';
}
```